# Make sure 'QAbstractSocket::SocketState' is registered using qRegisterMetaType()

Tags: c++, qt, websocket, qt5.3, qtwebsockets

I tried to put a `QWebSocket` connection into a `QThread`

```
QThread *thread = new QThread;



connect(&websocket,&QWebSocket::connected,this,&Widget::onWsConnect);

websocket.moveToThread(thread);
connect(thread, &QThread::finished, &websocket, &QObject::deleteLater);
websocket.open(wsUrl);

thread->start();
```

The program compiled without errors and is running normal, but when it tried to connect to the websocket server throws this error:

> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QAbstractSocket::SocketState'
>   (Make sure 'QAbstractSocket::SocketState' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)

When I do

```
websocket.open(wsUrl);
```

without threading the connection works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send your object through queued signal/slot connections, you should use `qRegisterMetaType<T>()`. Just call it before opening the socket some where in the constructor :

```
qRegisterMetaType<QAbstractSocket::SocketState>();
```

Comment: @Alfredocubitos would it be possible to share an example of the threaded websocket.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry. It's too long ago :-(

Answer (score 2):

The previous (Nejat's) answer is good as direct answer on how to attach the signal to slot in this case. But why do you want to start the web-socket on an additional thread? I start that same Qt WebSocket from main thread and it does no block it. The time to start that type of socket itself is negligible. I guess websocket uses some kind of OS non-blocking IO (likeliest) or spawns another thread internally (less likely). Other than blocking or doing massive computation you probably don't have a good reason for spawning a new thread and then taking care of managing it and additional communication overhead.

Comment: Upvoting this because lots of times people's first reaction is "I know, let me make a new thread!" when that's usually a terrible idea. Especially with an event-driven framework like Qt.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to maintain a list of open websocket connections, and when a particular connection gets a request, spawn a thread to handle the request and continue processing new connections/requests on the main thread.  Then, when the thread is done processing the request, it signals the main thread that it's done, along with the response.  The main thread would then receive the response from the thread and send it out over the open connection.  You could use std::async and std::future to accomplish this.

Comment: I know it's an old post, but would you happen to have more details to share regarding how to implement this in detail? Would you use QFuture?